# Is there Any third party utilities for wcf

Tags: .net, wcf

is there any paid third party helpers/Utilities making wcf services easier for advanced operations using c#.if any there suggest me.

Comment: Would you like to create wcf service using some other tool,right? Why?

Comment: What advanced operations do you mean?

Comment: @vipin I already created wcf service application,now i want to handle few things like -> How to reconnect automatically if wcf service is disconnected during any operation --> I want to keep the service session even if it idle for longer duration --> during any operation if any error occurs if service goes to faulted exception i want service to reconnect and continue operation where it left before exception

Comment: You question is too vague, you should ask more specific questions.

Comment: @RaviKumar, Its better to log those exceptions and handle it. There is so may way to log your information in Microsoft platform.